# How to iterate through lorem ipsum sentences

Tags: lipsum

I would like to be able to iterative through the lorem ipsum text in the `lipsum` package sentence by sentence. I am using this to simulate a list and it is quite apparent when the same text is repeated over and over again. This is not ideal so I would like the iterator to pick up from where it left off each time I use it. Each time I call this command I should just have to supply the number of sentences I want.

Here is an example I started with so you can see what I mean by the text being repeated over and over.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
    \item \lipsum[-][-5]
    \item \lipsum[-][-2]
    \item \lipsum[-][-1]
    \item \lipsum[-][-11]
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image: Screenshot of Latex Output for Inadequate Example]

Answer (score 3):

To solve this problem I created the command demonstrated in the following minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcounter{acounter}
\setcounter{acounter}{0}
\newcommand{\lipsumiterator}[1]{
    \lipsum[-][\arabic{acounter}+1-\arabic{acounter}+#1]
    \addtocounter{acounter}{#1}
    % max value is 2191
}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
    \item \lipsumiterator{5}
    \item \lipsumiterator{2}
    \item \lipsumiterator{1}
    \item \lipsumiterator{11}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image: Screenshot of Latex Output for Minimal Working Example]

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `\ducklist` or `\ducklistlist` macros from the `duckuments` package to create a dummy list:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{duckuments}

\begin{document}

\ducklist{itemize}

\ducklistlist{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

My idea is to unpack a lipsum paragraph, split it into sentences and look whether we have enough sentences; if not, the next lipsum paragraph is split and so on.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[nopar]{lipsum}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\lipsumiterator}{m}
 {% #1 = number of desired sentences
  \partphysics_iterator:n { #1 }
 }

% the current lipsum paragraph index
\int_new:N \g_partphysics_iterator_current_int
% the sentence container
\seq_new:N \g_partphysics_iterator_sentences_seq
% the sentence to typeset
\tl_new:N \l__partphysics_iterator_sentence_tl

\cs_new_protected:Nn \partphysics_iterator:n
 {
  \__partphysics_iterator_available:n { #1 }
  \prg_replicate:nn { #1 }
   {
    \seq_gpop_left:NN \g_partphysics_iterator_sentences_seq \l__partphysics_iterator_sentence_tl
    \tl_use:N \l__partphysics_iterator_sentence_tl.~
   }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__partphysics_iterator_available:n
 {
  \int_compare:nF { #1 < \seq_count:N \g_partphysics_iterator_sentences_seq }
   {
    \int_gincr:N \g_partphysics_iterator_current_int
    \use:e { \exp_not:N \unpacklipsum[ \int_eval:n { \g_partphysics_iterator_current_int }]}
    \seq_set_split:NnV \l_tmpa_seq { . } \lipsumexp
    \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_tmpa_seq
     {
      \tl_if_blank:nF { ##1 }
       {
        \seq_gput_right:Nn \g_partphysics_iterator_sentences_seq { ##1 }
       }
     }
    \__partphysics_iterator_available:n { #1 }
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
    \item \lipsumiterator{5}
    \item \lipsumiterator{2}
    \item \lipsumiterator{1}
    \item \lipsumiterator{11}
    \item \lipsumiterator{11}
    \item \lipsumiterator{11}
    \item \lipsumiterator{11}
    \item \lipsumiterator{11}
\end{itemize}

\lipsumiterator{120}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The example runs three pages, actually.